# angular.js get controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm working on a multiple platform app and I'm using angular.js. I have a controller where I have defined several actions (e.g. when the user clicks on an item the controller action navigates to a different side). It works great when I'm using HTML and angular.js but because it's an app for smartphones as well I will use the GoBack-Button to navigate to the start page if the current page is an other than the start page.

But the I can only assign a function to the event that the GoBack-Button is pressed in Javascript. So here's my question:

How can I get access to an angular-controller within a javascript file?

Here is my summarized code

ang.js:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", [])
    app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [{
            key: "Object 1",
            data: "Lorem Ipsum"
        },{
            key: "Object 2",
            data: "Lorem Ipsum"
        },{
            key: "Object 3",
            data: "Lorem Ipsum"
        }];

        this.actions = {
            goToStart: function () {
                // Navigates to the start page
            },
            goToPage1: function () {
                // Navigates to page 1
            },
            goToPage2: function () {
                // Navigates to page 2
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

site.js:

```
(function () {
    // ....

    function onDeviceReady() {
        device.addEventHandler("backbutton", onBackButtonPressed);
    }

    function onBackButtonPressed() {
        // Here I like to use the MyController.actions.goToStart() function
    }

    // ...
})();
```

Comment: you can add ng-click in your Html page so that it will call $scope's function

Comment: Yeah but this wouldn't handle the backbutton event, would it? I mean the hardware button not a software html button.

Comment: It should work on back-button also If you are on same page because angular is used for single page application

Comment: Again, I can't add a handler to the backbutton event in HTML it's only accessable in javascript.

Comment: there is an hack available                                                       controllerBody = angular.element(document.body);      controllerRootScope = controllerBody.scope().$parent;  but I would not suggest it afterall you can use it then you can $broacast any method using controllerRootScope